How to remove Ubuntu from SSD which I don't have root privileges for?
I've tried DBAN, Gparted on a live USB, dd command to override with zeroes and random values for several cycles (which I now think was a mistake), sudo rm -rf /mnt/nvme0n1 which is my drive mounted on the system. I'm tired because I can't use my SSD which I paid for. Please help!!! I lost root privileges because of my another silly mistake which was sudo chmod 444 / -R and something similar as root user in advanced mode.
BEFORE -
Image after I clicked delete for all partitions on my disc
AFTER - The partitions coming back as they were regardless
It sure looks like I accidentally swapped the images from before and after but I can assure you that's not the case. The partitions do not delete and are an actual pain.

Gparted on a Live USB should have worked, as sudo will work on it. Try that again...carefully to avoid silly mistakes.

Your rm commands has you working on files on a file-system, but the file-system will remain as your rm won't touch that.  Your approach or understanding is in error.

You see guys, the gparted thing says it was successful in formatting the SSD and everything but the OS files just come back as they were, I'm not kidding!
And about rm, I used it so I thought I'd get my SSD back as clean.

Your chmod command made everything non-executable -- don't be surprised that nothing works.  Reinstalling your OS will be far easier than fixing permissions correctly.  Then you can deal with your SSD.

Yes ubfan1, I've installed ubuntu in my HDD and tried ubuntu boot-repair and also os-uninstaller but it didn't work. OS in my HDD works fine but nothing's helping me to get rid of the OS in my SSD.

@ubfan1 I've added images as proof of my problem. please help if possible. I can provide more details if needed.

@guiverc I've added images as proof of my problem. please help if possible. I can provide more details if needed.

@device0 Notice the exclamation mark near the nvme0n1p2 - that shows there is some sort of problem. Right-clicking on it and then click "Information" then post that in your question. Finally, are you booting off of that disk?

dd is only necessary if you really want to make the data unrecoverable. Random data & multiple passes are necessary but that takes a long time.
Deleting the partition should be enough if you simply want to re-use the disk. Go to "Show Apps" -> Disks, select the NVME, delete any partitions on it. Now you can create a new partition and use it however you like.
You should be able to change the permissions back via:
sudo 755 -R / but there might be specific permissions for certain things and I don't know what those are.

I can't delete partitions, I can't add images I guess but when I try to do so in disks, it just doesn't happen. Gparted says it's done but the files are unaffected. I have also tried to uninstall os and repair os from yabuntu. Do you guys know some other ways?


Are you sure you are deleting the right partition? How about you post a screenshot? 2. If the partition is in use it will require a reboot. Make sure you are not deleting your system partition.


I've added images as you've asked friend, please help me if you have any possible solution for this.
